# Ec2 instance creation using terraform assigns public IP

Tags: terraform

I am super new to terraform, I tried creating a ec2 instance, a elb and cname record using terraform. There is `main.tf` file with config supporting this and a separate variable file.

I haven't defined to create a public ip for ec2 instance anywhere in the config but it still creates one. Kindly advice how to prevent this.

Comment: Probably that's the case because you are launching the instance in a subnet with the setting "auto-assign public IPv4 address" enabled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an `Boolean` option to disable to assign public ip address with an instance.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#associate_public_ip_address

> associate_public_ip_address - (Optional) Associate a public ip address with an instance in a VPC. Boolean value.

So your code can be updated to

```
resource "aws_instance" "foo" {
  ...
  ecs_associate_public_ip_address = "false"
}
```

Comment: Beware, if the subnet has the `Auto-assign public IPv4 address` set, this option is not considered.